# How to use "nvv4l2camerasrc" to record MJPG video with Python OpenCV on Jetson Nano

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am attempting to utilize the power of nvidia components to facilitate faster recording of video footage through the use of a usb-camera. To achieve this, I am taking advantage of the advanced acceleration capabilities that nvidia offers, which are specifically designed to enhance the performance of video recording. This should allow me to capture high-quality video quickly and efficiently, with minimal fuss. With this setup, I am confident that I will be able to record the best possible video recordings, without sacrificing on quality or speed.

My Code:

```py
import cv2

width = 2560
height = 1440
framerate = 30

gs_pipeline = f"nvv4l2camerasrc device=/dev/video0 " \
              f"! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width={width}, height={height}, format=MJPG, framerate={framerate}/1 " \
              f"! nvvidconv " \
              f"! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx " \
              f"! videoconvert " \
              f"! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR " \
              f"! appsink"

v_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gs_pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
if not v_cap.isOpened():
    print("failed to open video capture")
    exit(-1)

while v_cap.isOpened():
    ret_val, frame = v_cap.read()
    if not ret_val:
        break

    cv2.imshow('', frame)

    input_key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if input_key != -1:
        print(f"input key = {input_key}")

    if input_key == ord('q'):
        break

v_cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error I got:

```
[ WARN:0] global /home/nvidia/host/build_opencv/nv_opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (711) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Error opening bin: could not link nvv4l2camerasrc0 to nvvconv0, neither element can handle caps video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)2560, height=(int)1440, format=(string)MJPG, framerate=(fraction)30/1
```

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs because `nvv4l2camerasrc` can't handle those caps, in specific due to `format=MJPG` parameter.

You can figure out what caps and *formats* the element supports by simply inspecting on the element with the GSt Inspect tool:

```bash
gst-inspect-1.0 nvv4l2camerasrc
...
  SRC template: 'src'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      video/x-raw(memory:NVMM)
                  width: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
                 height: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
                 format: { (string)UYVY }
         interlace-mode: { (string)progressive, (string)interlaced }
              framerate: [ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ]
```

As you can see it could be [UYVY](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000365.shtml). So, changing MJPG to UYVY it's the what you want.

Additionally, you would want to retrieve your camera caps capabilities with the following V4L2 tools command, per example:

```bash
v4l2-ctl --device /dev/video0 --all
...
Format Video Capture:
    Width/Height      : 1280/960
    Pixel Format      : 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
    Field             : None
    Bytes per Line    : 2560
    Size Image        : 2457600
    Colorspace        : sRGB
    Transfer Function : Rec. 709
    YCbCr/HSV Encoding: ITU-R 601
    Quantization      : Default (maps to Limited Range)
```

Make sure the width and height you're pulling from the camera it's accord to the output you get from this command.